# DatePicker date format issue with custom format

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

My PC has a custom date format

```
PC1 = 31/Oct/2016
PC1 - IIS installed on this pc(PC1)
```

While the JQuery `DatePicker` shows only `10/31/2016` and tries to save this into the C# DataBase, it throws the error

> Invalid date format.

I don't want to hard code the `DatePicker` format and instead want to automatically inherit the date format according to PC settings.

Please let me how to do that.

## Edited

```
 $("#txtDBOEdit").datepicker(
            {    
               // dateFormat:'dd/MMM/yyyy' works fine but I dont want to hard code format and adopt format automatically from local machine.
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                maxDate: 0,
                yearRange: "-100:+0",
                minDate: new Date(year, month, day),
                defaultDate: new Date(year + 50, month, day)
            });
```

## C#

```
var dob = _db.Users.Where(w => w.UserNumber == user.UserNumber).FirstOrDefault();
if (dob != null)
{
  dob.DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(user.testDate);  
  // user.testDate='10/31/2016' which is comming for datepicket which is default date format.
  //dob.DOB = Convert.ToDateTime("04/JAN/2016");  it works fine because it is according to local pc custom date foramt
}
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks in Advance
and regards

Comment: Can you post your code to the question for review. Please take a look at - [ask]

Comment: Seriously improved formatting and fixed some formatting and title issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Datetime.Parse()

```
dob.DOB = DateTime.Parse(user.testDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I want to display datepicker without hard coded format. Datepicker automatically grab format from local machine where IIS installed

Comment: How ever what I did. I am not sure I am right or wrong. I hide format extracted from C# backend into html control then reference it to datepicker